# Open set in terms of nets

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, nets

Let $X$ be a topological space, and $U\subseteq X$ be a subset of $X$ with the following property:

> For every convergent net $x_\alpha\to x$ in $X$ such that $x\in U$, there exists an $\alpha$ such that $x_\alpha\in U$.

Is then $U$ open?

Note that I am *not* requiring that $x_\beta\in U$ for $\beta\ge\alpha$.

If this is false, what is a counterexample? I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: There are many of them. A constant net on a $T_1$ space, where every singleton closed. The set of acumulation points of a net in a connected space (to ensure that it isn't clopen).

Comment: @Dog_69 I don't understand your comment. The condition is required to hold for all nets, not just one in particular.

Comment: Yes I misunderstood the question. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $U$ is not open. Then $X \setminus U$ is not closed and we find $x \in U$ such that $x \in \overline{X \setminus U}$. Choose a net $(x_\alpha)$ in $X \setminus U$ such that $x_\alpha \to x$. By assumption some $x_\alpha \in U$ which is impossible.

Therefore $U$ must be open.

Comment: Don't you mean $x\notin U$?

Comment: @user839372 I mean $x \notin X \setminus U$ which means $x \in U$.